# Linear Algebra: links between rank and characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank, characteristic-polynomial

Question:

The characteristic polynomial of a square matrix B  is given as $t^2(t^2+1)$. From this information, deduce all the possible values of rank($B^2$)

Here is my attempt so far:

The degree of the characteristic polynomial p(t)=4. The eigenvalues are 0, $\pm i $. The rank corresponds to the number of non-zero eigenvalues.

My confusion starts here, since the eigenvalues are complex.

I would appreciate any help with this question. Thank you.

Comment: By Cayley-Hamilton you know that $B^2(B^2+1)=0$, so the minimal polynomial of $B^2$ divides $t(t+1)$.

Comment: why did you post this 1 hour after your original now duplicate post?  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4139839/linear-algebra-link-between-rank-and-characteristic-polynomial . other than an insertion of $n\times n$ these are identical.

Comment: Thank you all for your help

Comment: Yes, this is my first time posting, I put this up an hour ago, but it was removed for a time by an admin so I reposted it.

Answer (score 0):

Well in general it holds that rank$(AB) \leq$ min$($rank$(A), rank(B)$) so in your case we get:

rank$(A^2) \le $rank$(A)$. From here it quickly follows that rank$(A)=1$ or $2.$

From here you can probably figure out the rest.